# Bootstrap typeahead list upward direction

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using twitter bootstrap typeahead on the bottom side of a dialog.
I want to make typeahead list always appear upward direction. 
How can i do that? i cant find any option to make it appears upward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is supported by Bootstrap itself.

But it is achievable. 
It looks like the position is determined here 
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js#L65 but I haven't tried to mess with it.   The best thing would be to override the show function for typeahead, or you can just modify the boostrap.js file itself.  Though you'll have to redo your modifications if you ever upgrade.

Comment: The link is not valid now. Can you post the content here if you remember?